# rails 3 dynamic select field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

using this example on dynamic list  https://github.com/sandeepleo11/Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-3 I managed to get dynamic select in my form where I add a car, so when I select a carname in the next select field I get only car models that belongs to car I selected, Workin fine in this form.

So I decided to get this thing also in my search form, you select a car and based on that you select a car model and get the results. here is the website with search form http://ec2-107-22-183-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com/cars.

the problem here is that when I select a car I get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/dynamic_search/6"):` in console, 6 means I picked a car name who's id is 6 and the select field for carmodels displays all models available.

here is some code I have for the search form and dynamic search:

**_search.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :carname_id_equals, "Select Car Make" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :carname_id_equals, Carname.order('name ASC').all,  :id, :name, :include_blank => 'All' %>
    <%= f.label :carmodel_id_equals, "Select Model" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :carmodel_id_equals, Carmodel.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name, :include_blank => 'All' %>
    <% end %>
```

**dynamic_search.js.erb**

```
$('#search_carmodel_id').empty();
<% for carmodel in @carmodels %>


   // alert(<%= carmodel.id %>);

      $('#search_carmodel_id').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",<%= carmodel.id %>).text('<%= carmodel.name %>'));


<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
post "dynamic_carmodels/:id" => "cars#dynamic_search"
```

**controller**

```
def dynamic_search
    @carmodels = Carmodel.find_all_by_carname_id(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**application.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//    jQuery('#search_carmodel_id_equals').html("<option value=''>Select Carmodel</option>");
    jQuery('#search_carname_id_equals').change(function() {

        var data=$('#search_carname_id_equals').val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
             url: "http://"+location.host+"/dynamic_search/"+data,
            data: data,

            beforeSend: function()
            {
                //      alert('hi');
                //$('#status').html('<img src="loading.gif">');

            },

            success: function(response)
            {
                 //  alert(response);
                //  $('#search_carmodel_id_equals').html(html);    //dynamic_search.js.erb
                   //      $('#status').html(html);


            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

**routes** is the problem:

```
post "dynamic_carmodels/:id" => "cars#dynamic_search"
```

should be

```
post "dynamic_search/:id" => "cars#dynamic_search"
```

and **dynamic_search.js.erb**

```
$('#search_carmodel_id_equals').empty();
<% for carmodel in @carmodels %>


   // alert(<%= carmodel.id %>);

      $('#search_carmodel_id_equals').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",<%= carmodel.id %>).text('<%= carmodel.name %>'));


<% end %>strong text
```